# '=' symbol at the end shows encryption

Tags: encryption

I am using 128-bit Rijndael with ECB cipher mode encryption to convert my string. It formats some kind of string with symbols `==` or `=` at the end.

In my code I need some preliminary decision was this string encrypted. Can I suggest that if it contains `=` symbol at the end it is encrypted or possible cases when I will not get `=` symbol in the end in encrypted string?

Answer (score 2):

First of all, if you are using ECB you are not really "encrypting" since it is a broken cipher mode (see: http://bobnalice.wordpress.com/2009/01/28/friends-don%E2%80%99t-let-friends-use-ecb-mode-encryption/ )

Secondly, the = signs you are seeing are the Base64 padding characters.  They are only tagentially related to encryption since Base64 is used for any kind of binary data, not just encrypted date.

Thirdly, you can't even rely on the = sign always being present for Base64 data... it is only added for certain lengths of data (i.e. you could have encrypted, Base64 data that has no = sign)

Answer (score 0):

As @JoelFan points out, those '=' characters are Base64 padding which aren't part of the encryption at all, and aren't always there either if the data comes out to the right number of characters naturally.

You need to add something "out of band". I would replace the potentially-encrypted string with a class which has a string member for the data, and an "encrypted" flag. Once you're there, throw in a `getData()` method that checks if the instance's data is encrypted, returns the unencrypted value of the data if so (and may cache the plaintext in a private member for later, if it'll be accessed a lot), or just returns the plain text if it's not encrypted.